# what ideas for understanding my app that an copied audio file from other place to folder that belongs with my program is not belong it surely

Tags: android

i am programming an app for android.in that I record audios and save them to sdcard.i added name of them to a list. then audios saved to sdcard too.
now i want when an audio file that created by my app
relate with my app.means when i change thats name in sdcard,change name in list in my app,or when i delete one of them in sdcard ,it be deleted in my list.i dont want save audios info in database or arraylist.
i heared about "uri".may be help that??
can help anybody????please help me. what can i do?please... 
//////////
dont have problem with create file or directory just i want know how any update on sdcard how can update my list or how my app knows its audio files that created by it.

how understands my app that an copied audio file from other place to folder that belongs with my program is not belong it surely...

this idea i was that every time an audio created then listing all audio on my folder on sdcard again.
but this some problem,because maybe people chagne or modify(such as copy other audios to my folder or rename that or modify one of audios by cut or merge)
now app how understand this event?
your help will be appreciate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**i want when an audio file that created by my app relate with my app.**

First I'll assume that you are saving the audio files created by your app in your dynamically created folder structure for your app.
Try maintaining a separate folder for all audio files.

Then, you can easily retrieve the files list using 
[http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29)

Once you get the File objects array, you can get the names of the file using 
[http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29)

and create an array of Strings out of it.Then display them in your apps list.

This way you do not need to worry about deletion or addition.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it is first time i come in.i am very happy for your help